# Circularly symmetric complex gaussian (CSCG)

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance

I am studying the research paper in which Circularly symmetric complex gaussian distribution (CSCG) is some time denoted as CN(0,sigma^2In) where In is unit matrix. What is the significance of "In" in this representation. Because in some cases CSCG distribution is also denoted as CN(0,Sigma^2) i.e, without "In". Thanks in advance.........

Comment: ${\bf I}_n$ is the $n$-dimensional identity matrix.

Comment: ... and $\sigma^2 I_n$ is the covariance matrix.

Comment: @ david and @ robert, Thank you so much .

Comment: Hello all, I want to generate in matlab  a random variable  with CN(0,sigma^2In), where n = 50. Thanks in advance....